# How to properly configure application in Live Connect and project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: authentication, configuration, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-account

My question here is pretty simple: how to properly (and 100%) configure both Live Connect and project in Visual Studio 2013 in order for the **local** application run and authenticate an user properly against Microsoft account.

My question may be simple, but the answer is most likely not as simple. I've been reading countless articles and possible tutorials about this, but they are all fragmented and divided into small parts that do not really conciliate each other.

So below is the situation better described, with the steps I have followed.

**[Steps Followed]**

1) I have created a simple MVC application using Visual Studio 2013.

2) I have configured the project (using its properties) to use **IIS Express** with current Project Url : `https://localhost:44302/`

The project runs quite well, and external authentication with Facebook, Google and Twitter run very well too. Now for the tricky part:

3) I have created account with Microsoft and successfully created application in the Live Connect Developer Center.

4) Since configuring the field **Redirect URLs** to a simple `http://localhost:<port>` will not work (well...just because they didn't want it to, I suppose), I have additionally done the following..

5) Mapped in hosts file the following domain to localhost: `# 127.0.0.1 mytestdomain.localtest.me`

6) Reconfigured in Live Connect the **Redirect URLs** field to use the newly mapped domain: `http://mytestdomain.localtest.me` (although I have tried this with or without the port as well).

**[End result]**

With this configuration, the site runs properly locally. However, when I try to sign in with Microsoft account credentials (so, when I click the "Microsoft" button), I have redirected and received the following message:

**"We're unable to complete your request
Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later."**

I honestly do not understand why wouldn't this work, when a couple of articles suggested that doing these specific steps would make it work.

What can I be missing, why would this happen at all?

If someone can write here what am I missing and we could all join effort and create in this topic a full fledged, 100% working configuration for local application testing with Microsoft authentication, I believe it would help **everyone**. If such topic already exist and you can point me to it (because clearly I have missed it) it would also be great.

Thank you in advance,

Mad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just found out a proper and direct answer to my question. I totally missed it somehow during the last few days of research.

Microsoft's blog has all you need to make it work, and now mine does too. No big explanations and discussions, just basic and direct step by step article.

For those who could not find it and stumbled upon my topic here in StackOverflow, here is the link. Follow it word by word, and it **will** work.

**Answer :** [Configuring your ASP.NET application for Microsoft OAuth account](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/19/configuring-your-asp-net-application-for-microsoft-oauth-account.aspx)